# DynamicMetaObject for a ref return

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying - for *reasons* - to get a `ref return` indexer of my class work when it's stored in a `dynamic` variable.

I.e. I want the following code to somehow work (notice the `dynamic` in the 2nd part).

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var rr = new RefReturn();
    rr[0] = 1;
    rr[0]++;
    IncInt(ref rr[0]);
    Debug.Assert(rr[0] == 3);

    var dyn = (dynamic)rr;
    dyn[0] = 1;
    dyn[0]++;
    IncObj(ref dyn[0]);
    Debug.Assert((int)dyn[0] == 3);
}

class RefReturn
{
    private int i;
    public ref int this[int ix] => ref i;
}

static void IncInt(ref int i) => i++;
static void IncObj(ref object i) => i = (int)i + 1;
```

I got the following code, which is almost, but not quite, enough.

```cs
class RefReturn: IDynamicMetaObjectProvider
{
    private int i;
    public ref int this[int ix] => ref i;

    #region support dynamic indexers
    public DynamicMetaObject GetMetaObject(Expression parameter)
    {
        return new DynamicRefReturn(parameter, this);
    }

    public object GetIndexNoRef(int ix) => i;
    public object SetIndexNoRef(int ix, int value) => i = value;
    #endregion
}

class DynamicRefReturn : DynamicMetaObject
{
    public DynamicRefReturn(Expression expression, object value) : base(expression, BindingRestrictions.Empty, value)
    {
    }

    public override DynamicMetaObject BindSetIndex(SetIndexBinder binder, DynamicMetaObject[] indexes, DynamicMetaObject value)
    {
        return new DynamicMetaObject(
                Expression.Call(
                    Expression.Convert(Expression, LimitType),
                    LimitType.GetMethod("SetIndexNoRef"),
                    indexes[0].Expression,
                    Expression.Convert(value.Expression, typeof(int))
            ),
            BindingRestrictions.GetTypeRestriction(Expression, LimitType)
        );
    }

    public override DynamicMetaObject BindGetIndex(GetIndexBinder binder, DynamicMetaObject[] indexes)
    {
        return new DynamicMetaObject(
            Expression.Call(
                Expression.Convert(Expression, LimitType),
                LimitType.GetMethod("GetIndexNoRef"),
                indexes[0].Expression
            ),
            BindingRestrictions.GetTypeRestriction(Expression, LimitType)
        );
    }
}
```

With this, the code compiles and runs without exceptions... But since we aren't returning a `ref int` anymore, the value isn't changed at `IncObj(ref dyn[0]);`.
And we can't return `ref int` from a `System.Linq.Expressions.Expression` as far as I'm aware (but I hope I'm wrong).

Is there a way to fix this?

*Alternatively*, is there a way to detect this case in `BindGetIndex` and throw, somehow?

I hope this is possible *somehow*, because the somewhat similar example in VB.NET just works.

```vb
Sub TestByRefArrayItem()
    Dim arr(0 To 5) As Byte
    arr(0) = 1
    IncByte(arr(0))
    Debug.Assert(arr(0) = 2)

    Dim dyn As Object
    dyn = arr
    dyn(0) = 1
    IncObject(dyn(0))
    Debug.Assert(dyn(0) = 2)
End Sub
```